# how to access website stored on xammp via static public ip

Tags: xampp

I have designed a website. Almost all settings are done such as port forwarding in router etc. The website is also accessed on any computer through internet using static public ip but displays text only without any css effects, images etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the CSS styles, images, JS files, etc. are not displayed outside the localhost (from your IP address), it must be because when you specify the URL or location of those files, you give an absolute URL which works just for localhost.

For example, if you have

```
htdocs/
    index.html
    css/
        stylesheet.css
    img/
        logo.jpeg
        slider-1.png
        slider-2.png
        slider-3.png
```

This will work just in localhost (the computer where xampp is installed):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/css/stylesheet.css">
<img src="http://localhost/img/logo.jpeg">
ETC.
```

If you want it to work also outside your computer you should use relative paths:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stylesheet.css">
<img src="/img/logo.jpeg">
ETC.
```

This is because the HTML code is executed in the client side (in the person who visits your page's computer) so they can't access your files through localhost...

I hope this helps you, I was going to ask you which type of URLs do you use through the comments before answering but I can't add any comments because of my reputation :v

Comment: Thank you Jorge Bruned for the answer